# What is the difference between an exponential func. and a hyperbolic secant func.?

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, physics, hyperbolic-functions

All coefficients/constants remaining the same, what is the dif. between them? physically and mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperbolic trig functions are built from combinations of exponential functions.  I would say a defining characteristic on an exponential function call it $f$ is that $$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$$
i.e. $$e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$$
You can check that this is not the case for the hyperbolic secant function.
$$sech(x)=\frac{2}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$
Another difference is that sech(x) is bounded; the limit at $\infty$ and $-\infty$ is finite.